# Duda ej. PSEINT

Tags: pseint

Tengo este programa que calcula la cantidad de horas minutos y segundos pero no sé como hacer en este ejercicio para que salga la cantidad de segundos correspondientes "que sobran" en el caso de que "sobren", como ven en la imagen me sale mal la cantidad de segundos.

```
    Algoritmo sin_titulo
    //Hacer un programa que ingrese por teclado un número total de segundos y que
        //luego pueda mostrar la cantidad de horas, minutos y segundos que existen en el valor
    //ingresado.
    
    Escribir "Ingrese el número total de segundos"
    Leer segundos
    
    t<-segundos / 3600 
    
    m<-segundos / 60 
    
    s<- m / 60
    
    Escribir t,"Horas" 
    Escribir m,"Minutos"
    Escribir s,"Segundos"
FinAlgoritmo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si ingresas el total de segundos, porque los dividis por 60?

Comment: podrías ir restando a "segundos" lo que te vaya quedando, para saber cuantos segundos sobran

Comment: @L.Ronquillo los segundos, no se deviden.... la logica para calcular cuanto tiempo hay en tantos segundos... es casi como la describe...

Comment: me refiero a la variable segundos, estoy suponiendo que quiere saber cuantas Horas, Minutos y segundos tiene en X cantidad de segundos (por decir, 67 segundos= 1 minuto 7 segundos); con eso en mente, pensaba que si a la variable `segundos` le resta lo que va calculando, tendría lo que necesita al final, pero creo que leí mal el ejercicio

Comment: en sí es lo que te comenta @gbianchi , a `s` no lo dividas entre 60 y creo que es todo